# Python Tkinter using pygame to play and pause audio giving error

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pygame

I am trying to make a simple mp3 player with tkinter and using pygame mixer function and the playing part of it works just fine but the pausing part is what I'm having trouble with. This is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from pygame import mixer
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("mp3 player")
fileEntry = Entry(root, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)
fileEntry.pack()
def PlayMusic():
    song = fileEntry.get()
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(song)
    mixer.music.play()
def PauseMusic():
    song = fileEntry.get()
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(song)
    mixer.music.pause()
    

playButton = Button(root, text = "Play", command = PlayMusic)
pauseButton = Button(root, text = "Pause", command = PauseMusic())
pauseButton.pack()
playButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

however it gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/person/file/file/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    pauseButton = Button(root, text = "Pause", command = PauseMusic())
  File "/Users/person/file/file/main.py", line 17, in PauseMusic
    mixer.music.load(songA)
pygame.error: No file '' found in working directory '/Users/person/file/file'.
```

I have no idea what is going on and I hope someone can please help me, Thanks!

Comment: Do you see the difference between `command = PlayMusic` and `command = PauseMusic()`?  One of those is specifying a function for the Button to call when it is clicked, and the other one is calling the function *right now*, and passing its return value (which is None) as the Button's action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably caused because `fileEntry` is empty.
This in turn is caused because you are *calling* `PauseMusic` in the creation of the pause button instead of referencing it. (As jasonharper has commented.)

Additionally, you don't need to load a song in the pause function.
Since you've already loaded and started playback in `PlayMusic`, you should only have to issue the pause command:

```
def PauseMusic():
    mixer.music.pause()
```

Furthermore, I would advise to move the `mixer.init()` outside of `PlayMusic`. Otherwise you might have problems if you press pause before play.